# The geometric meaning of certain mappings written in cylindrical or spherical coordinates

Tags: calculus, coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates

What is the geometric meaning of the following mappings, that are written in cylindrical coordinates?

The mappings are: $$(r, \theta, z) \rightarrow(r, \theta , -z) \\ (r, \theta , z) \rightarrow (r, \theta +\pi , -z)$$

And what is the geometric meaning of the following mappings, that are written in spherical coordinates?

The mappings are: $$(\rho , \theta , \phi) \rightarrow (\rho , \theta +\pi , \phi) \\ (\rho , \theta , \phi) \rightarrow (\rho , \theta , \pi-\phi)$$

Comment: That first looks like two mappings. Are you asking about each? Same for the second question.

Comment: Yes, I am asking for each... I edited my post, and added the plural... @ThomasAndrews

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the question includes two *pairs* of mappings. Nonetheless:

**Hint** One concrete way to see this is to write each of the coordinate triples involved in rectangular coordinates using the usual transformation rules. (Alternately, one can meditate a bit on the geometric meaning of each of the coordinates $r, \theta, z, \rho, \phi$. In fact, I think it would be instructive to do this concretely as above, and then "meditatively".)

Comment: Could you explain to me further what I have to do??

Comment: I'm off to teach, but if someone hasn't written a more explicit answer by the end of the day, I'll come back and expand my own to show how to use rectangular coordinates to understand one of the maps geometrically.

Answer (score 1):

(a) the mapping $$(r, \theta, z) \to (r,\theta, -z)$$ is the reflection on the plane $z = 0$ or the $xy$ plane.

(b) the mapping $$(r, \theta, z) \to (r,\pi + \theta, -z)$$ is the reflection on the plane $z = 0$ or the $xy$ plane followed by half rotation about the $z$-axis.

(c) the mapping $$(\rho, \theta, \phi) \to (r,\pi+\theta, \phi)$$ is the half rotation about the $z$-axis

(d) the mapping $$(\rho, \theta, \phi) \to (r,\theta, \pi-\phi)$$ is the reflection on the $xy$ plane.

Comment: Could you explain to me the cases $(b)$ and $(c)$ about the rotations?? How do we know that it is a rotation and that the rotation is about the $z-$axis??

Comment: @MaryStar, you can think of the $\theta$ coordinate as the amount of rotation about the $z$-axis needed to bring the $x$-axis to the projection of the point onto the $xy$-plane.

Comment: I got stuck right now... Could you explain it further to me??

Comment: you need to plot some points  $(r \theta, 0)$ on the $xy$ plane. see what the coordinates $r$ and $\theta$ mean. then plot pairs of points $(r, \theta), (r, \pi + theta)$  and see how they are related.

Comment: Ok, I will do that... I have also an other question... At $(a)$ do we have to prove that= it is the reflection on the plane $z=0$ or canwe just say that?? @abel

Comment: @MaryStar, i don't think there is a proof. these are geometric things to help you see better.

Comment: Do we have to justify it maybe using a graph??

Comment: @MaryStar, you mean a geometric figure/diagram. yes that would show that you understand what you are talking about. not the graph of a function. i did draw both cylindrical and spherical cartoons on a paper to visualize the mapping.

Comment: I tried to make such a geometric figure... I posted it as an answer... Could you tell me if it is correct??

Answer (score 0):

Is the geometric figure for the first one the following @abel ??

[image]

**EDIT1:**

[image]

**EDIT2:**

[image]

Comment: yes, very nice diagram.

Comment: For the second case how will be $\theta +\pi$ at the figure?? @abel

Comment: the green half should be rotated $180^\circ$ about the $z$-axis.

Comment: Is it as I have drawn in the second picture?? @abel

Comment: yes. that is correct. pictures are very nice. how do you make them and put them here.

Comment: I added now the figure for $(c)$. When we change $\theta$ will $\phi$ remains constant as it is now?? @abel

Comment: mary star, yes. the point is moving on the cone $\phi$ and  $z$ constant. only $\theta$ is increased by $\pi$ so that it goes diametrically opposite.

Comment: Do you mean as the picture that I added now??

Comment: if you can draw a circle at the top connecting the two points, that would be nice.

Comment: Do you mean like that?? Why should we do that?? Because these are points of a shpere??

Comment: i would draw a complete circle; not a half circle. but that is a personal choice.

Comment: Do you mean something like that?? @abel

Comment: no, the circle is at a constant $z,$ that is, on a horizontal plane.